# Kill query after command timout

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, devart

I'm trying to kill query triggered by ADO.NET command on postgresql database, after command timeout:

```
using (var command = new PgSqlCommand("public.timeout_test", connection))
{
    command.CommandTimeout = 10; 
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

In dotnet code timeout exception is being throwed correctly, but I wonder why query triggered by timout_test function is still in active state. If I run below query, then query executed by timeout_tets is listed as active:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity where state = 'active';
```

Tried to test it with devart and npgsql connectors, but both of them behave in the same way, so I assume that it's intended behevior, but don't understand the reason. Also wanted to ask if there is a way to kill query after command timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in Npgsql, CommandTimeout is implemented as a client-side socket timeout: after a certain amount of time Npgsql will simply close the network socket on its side. This doesn't cancel the query server-side, which will continue running.

You can set the PostgreSQL [`statement_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html) parameter to have it kill queries running more than a given amount of time; for best results, set `statement_timeout` to something lower than CommandTimeout - this will ensure that server timeout occurs before client timeout, preserving the connection and transmitting the server timeout to the client as a regular exception.

Another option is to manually trigger a cancellation from the client by calling `NpgsqlCommand.Cancel()`. You can do this whenever you want (e.g. when the user clicks a button), but contrary to `statement_timeout` it will obviously work only if the network is up.